# Printing float3& values in c++

Tags: c++

It might be a really trivial question but im getting parameters via the function

```
bool intersectRaySphere(const float3& p, const float3& d, const float3& c, float r, float& t)
```

And now i have to work with several of this parameters. So i tried so print values of float3& c in different ways like

```
float my_value = c[2];
std::cout << "SphereCenter: " <<  my_value << std::endl;
```

But im getting compiler errors every time... How do I do this correctly?

Comment: float3 is not a C++ type. Show please float3 typedef/struct/class

Comment: You seem to expect that float3 is an array float[3]. Most likely this is not the type. Can you post the error?

Comment: Thank you... yes - that was my mistake. I thought float3 is some standard type (3D vector) but of course - it was individual declared. Problem solved now.